# Create simple text popup for textview

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android and started to learn java, i found an app called learn java and i notice the popup appear when i tap a text view,here is a screen shot

[image]

is there a simple way to do this in android studio like `textview.showpoponupclick("text")` or i have to invent it,i saw some tutorials to make .XML and a lot of coding, but i only want to show some text similar to the `edittext.setError();` . and sorry for my English.

Comment: You can use external libraries like [this](https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do refer some external libraries like [this](https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips).

As sample use its layout XML like here provided

```
<com.nhaarman.supertooltips.ToolTipRelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_tooltipRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And create a tooltip view from java code

```
 ToolTipRelativeLayout toolTipRelativeLayout = (ToolTipRelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_tooltipRelativeLayout);

    ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip()
                        .withText("A view")
                        .withColor(Color.RED)
                        .withShadow()
                        .withAnimationType(ToolTip.ANIMATIONTYPE_FROMTOP);
    myToolTipView = toolTipRelativeLayout.showToolTipForView(toolTip, findViewById(R.id.activity_main_redtv));
    myToolTipView.setOnToolTipViewClickedListener(MainActivity.this);
```